# Можно ли как-то сделать проверку длины текста в Label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

```
x = Label(бла бла бла)

if x['text length=5']:
    и так далее
```

Чтобы можно было проверять длину текста.

Answer (score 2):

Метод `cget` позволяет получить значение любой из настроенных опций.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Password Generator")
root.geometry('600x400')
root.configure(background ="gray")

def gen():
    len_t1 = len(t1.cget("text"))                                      # <----
    len_t2 = len(t2.cget("text"))                                      # <----
    print(f'{len_t1}') 
    print(f'{len_t2}')                                  

    if len_t1 > 5:
        print('Hello') 
        
    if len_t2 == 9:
        print('World')     


t1 = Label(root, text='Password Generator', font=('Arial', 25), fg='green', background="gray")
t1.place(x=60,y=0)
t2 = Label(root,text='Password:',font=('Arial',14),background ="gray")
t2.place(x=145,y=90)


b = Button(root,text='Generate!',font=('Arial',14), fg='green',background="gray", command=gen)
b.place(x=230,y=195)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```py
if len(x['text']) == 5:
    бла бла бла
```